# Вчера они заехали в усадьбу Абрамцево (--) в их родовое гнездо. Нужно ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, приложение, уточнения

*Вчера они заехали в усадьбу Абрамцево (--) в их родовое гнездо, переночевали, отзавтракали и чуть свет тронулись на запряжных в город.*

Если тире ставится, значит мы выделяем приложение... Но разве приложение может относится к обстоятельству? **(куда?) в усадьбу Абрамцево -- (какую?) в их родовое гнездо**. Или это уточнение и здесь нужна запятая? однако выделенный запятой оборот сливается с однородными членами...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это пояснительная конструкция, а они обычно выделяются с помощью тире, а не запятой. (http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/724-28_utochnyayuschie__poyasnitelnye_i_prisoedinitelnye_chleny_predlozheniya.html)

Интуиция посказывает мне, что второе *в* здесь лишнее. Оно было бы уместо при уточнении, например: в усадьбу Абрамцево, в центральный дом.

Answer (score 1):

Возможные варианты:

***Вчера они заехали в усадьбу Абрамцево, их родовое гнездо. Переночевали, отзавтракали и чуть свет тронулись на запряжных в город.***

***Вчера они заехали в усадьбу Абрамцево — их родовое гнездо. Переночевали, отзавтракали и чуть свет тронулись на запряжных в город.***